# Prove ||u-v|| defines a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Given a normed linear space, I need to prove that $||U-V||$ defines a metric space. I can prove symmetry and positivity, but having trouble proving $||U-V||+||V-W||\geq ||U-W||$

I know  :

$$||U-W||\leq ||U||+||W||\\||U-V||+|V-W|| \leq ||U||+||W||+2||V||$$

But, if I put them together, I cant seem to prove that $||U||+||W||\leq||U-V||+||V-W||$

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hint: let $x = U - V$ and $y = V - W$. Then $\|x + y\| \le \ldots$

Comment: Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 2):

$$||U-W||=||(U-V)+(V-W)|| \leq ||U-V||+||V-W||$$